# MySql different order by conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have my mysql query

```
SELECT `adddate`, `pexpdate`, `level` FROM `localhost-tests` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `level` DESC, `pexpdate` DESC, `adddate` DESC
```

returns me

[image: mysql query result]

Problem is, if part with levels > 0 is fine, and sorted by pexpdate, second part, where level = 0, must be sorted by adddate, not pexpdate.

I've tried:

```
WHERE 1 ORDER BY ORDER BY `level` desc, `PExpDate` desc, `AddDate` desc
WHERE 1 ORDER BY IF(`level`, `PExpDate`, `AddDate`) DESC
WHERE 1 ORDER BY level DESC, ifnull(PExpDate, AddDate) DESC LIMIT 5
```

Question: How to sort part of result where level = 0 by adddate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple, multiply 2 columns and sort by result

```
SELECT *, `level` * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`pexpdate`) as `BonusDate` FROM `localhost-tests` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `BonusDate` DESC, `adddate` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `WHERE 1` part is useless. You don't need `WHERE` to specify an `ORDER` clause.

Then, use `UNION`.

```
SELECT `adddate`, `pexpdate`, `level` FROM `localhost-tests` WHERE `level` <> 0 ORDER BY `level` DESC, `pexpdate` DESC, `adddate` DESC
UNION
SELECT `adddate`, `pexpdate`, `level` FROM `localhost-tests` WHERE `level` = 0 ORDER BY `adddate` DESC
```

Comment: Doesn't want to order by each query separately but orders by last one. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION`

```
SELECT `adddate`, `pexpdate`, `level` FROM `localhost-tests` WHERE `level`>0 ORDER BY `level` DESC, `pexpdate` DESC
UNION
SELECT `adddate`, `pexpdate`, `level` FROM `localhost-tests` WHERE `level`=0 ORDER BY `adddate`
```

Answer (score 1):

try that without UNION

```
  SELECT `adddate`, `pexpdate`, `level` FROM `localhost-tests`
  ORDER BY CASE  WHEN `level`>0 THEN `level` , `pexpdate` , `adddate` 
                 WHEN `level`=0 THEN `adddate`
           END DESC
```